# Motor drive controlled by ESP32 (Arduino)

Tags: arduino, esp32, motordriver

I am testing a custom motor drive (small 6V DC motor) controlled by an ESP32 using Arduino code.
The direction A and B are controlled by High/Low digital writes on GPIO pins 16 & 17.
Using an NPN transistor ([NPN transistor - BC847 - datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1810301522_ON-Semiconductor-SBC847BLT1G_C232577.pdf)) and a  ([dual n/p mosfet IRF7105 - datasheet](http://file:///C:/Users/Jasper%20Gay/Downloads/1810010115_Infineon-Technologies-IRF7105TRPBF_C94064.pdf)).

The speed is controlled by PWM (ledc) on pin 26 with a mosfet:  ([IRLML2502 n-channel mosfet datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlml2502pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535668048e2606))

[Motor Drive - schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYmzD.png)

But the results are not consistent, when I set A or B high and PWM at 100%, I would expect close to 6V on the motor pins (1 and 2). Sometimes this is indeed the case, but sometimes I only measure 3.7V.
When the testpoint T6 is shorted to ground, the 6V is reached.
I am not even sure where the different voltage goes "missing", I measured the following voltages with my DMM (no oscilloscope available unfortunately).

- M1 - M2: 3.7V
- M1 to GND: 0V
- M2 to 6V: 6V

Is there something I am missing in the schematic or in the way I drive this with the ESP32?

Answer (score 0):

[Arduino.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ4DO.jpg)

```
 #include <Stepper.h>
    
    int stepCount = 0;
    Stepper Moteur=Stepper(5,6,7);
    
    void setup(){
      Serial.begin(9600);
    
    }
    void loop() {
      Moteur.step(2000);
      Serial.print("steps:");
      Serial.print(-stepCount);
      stepCount++;
      delay(0);
    }
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the response, but the driver is meant for a dc motor, not a stepper motor so I don't think this will help in this situation?